# How can i show on my browser what i see on Rviz?

Tags: ros2, rviz, ros-humble, rosbridge, webots

Im on ROS2-Humble and i want to see my robot's location and movement on the map, the way i see it on Rviz, on my browser.
[image] Like the picture above, I want from Rviz to get the Grid, RobotModel, TF, and Map, send it on my browser and show it there, kinda like streaming it or rendering it via a .js file and .html.
Im new with ROS2 and i cant seem to find any sources to help me. Most of the things i find are for ROS1 and Chat GPT doesnt help at all.
Basically something like this: https://answers.ros.org/question/319626/real-time-map-generate-on-web-like-a-rviz/

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who wants the same thing as me I ended up using https://github.com/MoffKalast/vizanti and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is not your intention to use third party tools but these worth giving a try:

- [Foxglove](https://foxglove.dev/ros)
- [webviz](https://webviz.io/)

If you don't want to deal with these, then by using **rosbridge_suite** you can do so:
[rosbridge_suite wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something similar to the [RobotWebTools](https://robotwebtools.github.io/) I haven't used it with ROS 2 but with ROS 1 it was working well afaik.

Comment: I have to work this out in ROS2, i already know about RobotWebTools and nothing helps from there cause most stuff arent configured for ROS2 yet. Thanks though!

Comment: You can use `ros_bridge` to bridge the topics to the ROS 1 and use it. I have used it couple years ago and only thing that was not working at that time was `rosaction`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dheera/rosboard

I have not tried this, but it could help.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer and explain why the link will help? Also, suggesting untested solutions isn't ideal.

Comment: Basically this just visualizes the active topics, i can already do that. Thanks for showing me rosboard though, it might help me in some other occasion.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* billy. Please *[be nice](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)*. For specific guidelines, see our [Code of Conduct](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks for your answer but we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) so answers which rely on a link can be rendered useless if the linked content disappears. If you add more context from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful. See [answer] for more info.

Comment: Fair enough. My apologies to the OP.